# regular expression in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

How to find whether the string contains '/' as last character .

I need to append / to last character if not present only

```
ex1 : def s = home/work 
    this shuould be home/work/     
ex2 : def s = home/work/
     this will remain same as home/work/
```

Mybad thought this is simple, but fails

thanks in advance

Comment: Solved : Should use endsWith('/'). thanks for the comments

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex, or you could use [`endsWith("/")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3):

The endsWith method posted above works and is probably clear to most readers.  For completeness, here's a solution using regular expressions:

```
def stripSlash(str) {
    str?.find(/^(.*?)\/?$/) { full, beforeSlash -> beforeSlash }
}

assert "/foo/bar" == stripSlash("/foo/bar")
assert "/baz/qux" == stripSlash("/baz/qux/")
assert "quux" == stripSlash("quux")
assert null == stripSlash(null)
```

The regular expression can be read as:

- from the start of the line: `^`
- capture a non-greedy group of zero or more characters in length: `(.*?)`
- that ends with an optional slash: `/?`
- followed by the end of the line: `$`

The capture group is then all that's returned, so the slash is stripped off if present.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
s?.endsWith( '/' )
```

So...some sort of normalisation function such as:

```
def normalise( String s ) {
  ( s ?: '' ) + ( s?.endsWith( '/' ) ? '' : '/' )
}

assert '/' == normalise( '' )
assert '/' == normalise( null )
assert 'home/tim/' == normalise( 'home/tim' )
assert 'home/tim/' == normalise( 'home/tim/' )
```

---

[edit] To do it the other way (ie: remove any trailing slashes), you could do something like this:

```
def normalise( String path ) {
  path && path.length() > 1 ? path.endsWith( '/' ) ? path[ 0..-2 ] : path : ''
}

assert '' == normalise( '' )
assert '' == normalise( '/' )
assert '' == normalise( null )
assert 'home/tim' == normalise( 'home/tim' )
assert 'home/tim' == normalise( 'home/tim/' )
```

Comment: how to remove / from last character if present only. i'm handling two cases in different scenarios. should omit / in last character.
ex: /home/tim/ should produce /home/tim  . thanks